# Bolded subtitle in the middle of document

Tags: titles, text

I have seen there are numerous posts on adding subtitles, but they seem to only pertain to adding subtitles immediately below the main title, or they add larger text that is not bolded. I have tried, for example, adding the package 'titling' and using \subtitle from there. I have tried changing my document class to scrartcl, where \subtitle supposedly works. It did not. I have gone through at least 10 stack exchange posts, and nothing seems to work. I simply want a bolded, slightly larger text, subtitle, for a short section of my document, without having to create a separate latex file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subtitle command in [KOMA-script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes is linked to the `\maketitle` command. To typeset the type of subtitles you describe, I suggest using the command `\addsec`, `\addchap` or `\minisec`\, depending on which documentclass you are using. They also have starred versions that ensure you do not get any text from the sectioning command in the running headers.

`addsec` has the same format as `\section`, without any numbering. See the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) pages 105--107 for what you can do.

Here is an MWE, and the output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\KOMAoptions{headings=small,%
            captions=tableheading,%
    }

% Section
\let\raggedsection\flushleft

\begin{document}
\title{Capital Asset Prices}
\author{W.\,T.\,F.\,Dull}

\maketitle

\section{Recitals}
\label{sec:intro}

\textsc{One of the problems} which has plagued the world is bad typesetting of subtitles. Now we have KOMA-script to help us.

\blindtext[1]

\let\raggedsection\centering
\addsec{Form of subtitle -- centred}
\let\raggedsection\flushleft

\blindtext[1]

\addtokomafont{minisec}{\huge}
\minisec{Minisec}

\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```